# Matching and study design

Tags: matching, case-control-study

I am currently designing a retrospective case-control study and am having some difficulty coming up with an adequate matching solution. The study assesses a specific surgical procedure and the only variable that makes sense to match on (i.e., is relatively random in its impact on the results while simultaneously being something we're not that interested in assessing the impact of) is year the surgery was done. Unfortunately, about 15 of the 75 patients in the case arm do not have control matches. In this situation is it best to just proceed with uneven numbers in each arm?

Alternatively, we could just randomly choose a matching number from our control patient pool not based on any specific variable.

Comment: Can you clarify? What exactly is the outcome of interest? You mean to match cases to controls right? Case status is usually thought of as the outcome, such as "death or infection due to complications" in a surgery. It seems, based on your description, that the surgery is the exposure of interest.

Comment: Both cases and controls receive the surgery of interest, but cases fail and controls succeed.

Comment: What is your exposure of interest? It can't be surgery in-and-of itself if all persons in the sample received the surgery.

Comment: Essentially we're taking a group of patients who succeeded the surgery and a group who failed and comparing them based on a short list of variables we think might have accounted for the difference.

Comment: Are you actually matching based on risk factors? If not you don't do anything, just fit the logistic regression model. Are cases matched 1:1 to controls?

Comment: We have hundreds upon hundreds of potential controls, but it would take far too long to collect the data on them so I am attempting to design the study to be powerful but reasonable. Matching is currently on year of surgery (these surgeries happened over multiple decades). Alternatively I was just going to randomly choose a matching number on no specific variables whatsoever.

Comment: That is exactly the rationale for doing a case-control design... so I'm failing to see what the question is. Are you interested in setting up chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25685/discussion-between-makaira-murakami-and-adamo).